# How to apply this VBA code to two specified sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to `VBA`, I need help applying the below VBA code to two specific work sheets `by Region` and `by Model`. The code simply finds the last column which has the name `total for the year` and copies the previous months values into a new column. The code works fine if executed on each worksheet separately.

```
Sub Insert_New_Col()
Dim R As Range, BeforeR As Long


'Find 'Totals' in row 5 of active sheet
Set R = Rows(3).Find(what:="Total for the Year", lookat:=xlWhole)

'identify the column to copy (last month)
BeforeR = R.Column - 1


    If R Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox ("The word 'Totals' was not found in Row 5 - macro terminated!")
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Not R Is Nothing Then

    'copy last month's column
    Columns(BeforeR).Copy

    'insert copied cells before the Totals column
    Columns(R.Column).Insert Shift:=xlRight


    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: So you want the exact same code to work as is on 2 different sheets?

Answer (score 2):

Create an array of sheets to loop through. The way this is set up, you can add as many sheets to the array as you need without any need to modify the macro. You will need to modify your `msgbox` since you no longer exit the sub when it fails to find a specified value - instead, you move on to the next sheet.

```
Sub Insert_New_Col()

Dim Found As Range, BeforeR As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet, xSheets As Variant
Dim i As Long

xSheets = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2") '<-- List of sheets to loop through

For i = LBound(xSheets) To UBound(xSheets)

    Set ws = xSheets(i)
    Set Found = ws.Rows(3).Find(What:="Total for the Year", Lookat:=xlWhole)
    BeforeR = R.Column - 1

    If Found Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("The word 'Totals' was not found in Row 5 on Sheet: " & ws.Name)
    Else
        Columns(BeforeR).Copy
        ws.Columns(R.Column).Insert Shift:=xlRight
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know why I keep getting run-time error 91? The error occurs at set found.

Comment: I think he left out the part of the code that sets the ws object from the xSheets variable.

Comment: `Set ws = xSheets(i)` is missing a reference to the appropriate `Worksheets` collection... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59380244/why-do-i-get-object-required-error-for-the-below-vba-code

Answer (score 0):

If your code works on 1 sheet, it can work on many.

Create a function with your code inside
and an argument of worksheet - something like:

```
myFunction(ws as Worksheet)
```

In another function or sub do this:

```
Dim myWorkSheets(2) As Worksheet

Set myWorkSheets(0) = Worksheets("Region")   '-- or Worksheets(1)
Set myWorkSheets(1) = Worksheets("Model")    '-- or Worksheets(2)

For Each ws In myWorkSheets
    myFunction (ws)
Next
```

or if you want to apply to all work sheets:

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    myFunction (ws)
Next
```

In 'myFunction' place 'ws' before ranges, cells, etc. e.g:

```
Set R = ws.Rows(3).Find(what:="Total for the Year", lookat:=xlWhole)
```

That's it.