# Why do I get object required error for the below VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA, I need help applying the below VBA code to two specific work sheets by Region and by Model. The code simply finds the last column which has the name total for the year and copies the previous months values into a new column. But I get an error object required at ws.

```
   Sub Insert_New_Col()

Dim Found As Range, BeforeR As Long
Dim xSheets As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

xSheets = Array("By Region", "By Model") '

For i = LBound(xSheets) To UBound(xSheets)

    Set ws = xSheets(i)
    Set Found = ws.Rows(3).Find(What:="Total for the Year", Lookat:=xlWhole)
    BeforeR = R.Column - 1

    If Found Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("The word 'Totals' was not found in Row 5 on Sheet: " & ws.Name)
    Else
        Columns(BeforeR).Copy
        ws.Columns(R.Column).Insert Shift:=xlRight
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an actual member of the `Worksheets` collection:

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(xSheets(i))
```

---

> `BeforeR = R.Column - 1`

What is `R`? Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module and declare all variables.

Comment: The code works fine if executed from the VBA Window or from any of the two sheets. I have the command button on an input sheet, when I run the code it just copies the cells in the input sheet and pastes it to the region and model sheets. How do I fix this so it only copies from the region and model sheets?

Comment: You need to qualify which sheet `Columns(BeforeR)` is on.